# Boolean to check if array contains a pair that sums to 0

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm doing a simple ruby challenge, which asked me to create a method two_sum?(arr), that returns true if the array contains a pair which adds up to 0. This can be 0 and 0, or -2 and + 2 etc. This challenge does not expect me to know .permutation, so I tried to do it this way --

```
def two_sum?(arr)
    arr.each do | obj |
        arr.each do | pair_obj |
         return true if obj + pair_obj == 0
        end
    end
    false   
end
```

When I run this with sample arrays however, I get true for any array that I pop in.

Any help in what I'm doing wrong? Is it not allowed to do arr.each twice?

Comment: Ohp, thanks for the clarifying question. I meant 1 pair. Question updated to reflect that :)

Comment: I don't see the relevance of `permutation` to this question. The method `combination` would be more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not return `true` for any array. `two_sum?([1, 2])` returns `false`.

There is one flaw in your logic. Your code will return `true` if the array includes a `0` even if it does not include two `0`s. I would write like this:

```
def two_sum?(arr)
  return true if arr.count(0) >= 2
  arr = arr - [0]
  arr.any?{|i| arr.any?{|j| (i + j).zero?}}
end
```

Comment: Ah! this is perfect. Thank you for the help. All the tests I ran had 0 in it, and I was confused with what was happening. This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
def two_sum? a
  a.count(0) > 1 || (a & a.map(&:-@)).size > 1
end

two_sum? [1,2,3,4,-2]
 # ⇒ true
two_sum? [1,0,3,4,0]
 # ⇒ true
two_sum? [1,2,3,4,0]
 # ⇒ false
two_sum? [1,2,3,4,5]
 # ⇒ false
two_sum? [1,2,3,-2,0]
 # ⇒ true
```

Comment: Your code returns false if there is a pair and a single zero (e.g `[1,2,3,4,-2,0]`)